# ERROR: Update canceled: attempt to update a target row with values from multiple join rows

Tags: netezza

This is my query that does not work in Netezza:

```
UPDATE  TABLE1  A
SET     A.COL1 = B.COL1
FROM    TABLE2  B
WHERE   A.ID  >= B.VALUE_START
AND     A.ID  <= B.VALUR_END
AND     A.COL2  = B.COL2
AND     A.COL3   = 'VALUE'
```

How do I re-write this query? Please help.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

As the error message says, you've got multiple rows in your TABLE2 that match (against any given row in TABLE1).  So the system doesn't know what values to stuff into TABLE1 ... since it has multiple possibilities (from TABLE2).

In the following example I'm going to use a simpler version of your original query (to make things simpler for me)

=> update table1 a set a.col2 = b.col2 from table2 b where a.col1 = b.col1;
ERROR:  Update canceled: attempt to update a target row with values from multiple join rows

So ... the same error you hit.  I can get rid of duplicates in table2 by doing the following.

=> update table1 a set a.col2 = b.col2 from (select col1, col2 from table2 group by 1,2)  b where a.col1 = b.col1;

Alhough this, too, might fail ... it depends on your data.  If TABLE2 looks like this

100|1
100|2
100|3

I would still end up with multiple rows in TABLE2 for the COL1 value of 100.  What value from COL2 is the system supposed to use?  1?  2?  3?